# Python Selenium: Unable to click on a user name field

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am attempting to locate a user name field that does not have an ID or other locator that I can easily find using Selenium Web Driver.

Using Chrome's Inspect Element, the HTML for this object is as follows

```
<div aria-hidden="true" style="cursor:text" data-bind="text: hintText, css: hintCss" class="placeholder">someone@example.com</div>
```

What would be the best way to locate this page object?

Thanks

Comment: use css selector. If not, try using class name.

Answer (score 0):

Either of these should work (if it is the first `div`-element of this class type)

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('placeholder')
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.placeholder')
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='placeholder']")
```

If there are more elements which match use the find_element**s** version of the methods and use the index of the returned list the get the element you need.

Answer (score 0):

To **`click()`** the `User Name` field you can use either of the following line of code :

- Using `class` and `text` attributes :

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='placeholder' and contains(text(),'someone@example.com')]"));
  ```
- Using `class` and `aria-hidden` attributes :

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='placeholder' and @aria-hidden='true']"));
  ```

Answer (score 0):

First find out is your element is inside different frame. Find the  iframe, first switch to that, after which you will able to locate your user desired object by using any method like find_elemet_by_class_name or find_element_by_css_selector or by xpath.
For switching to frame try below code:

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_id("ID_OF_YOUR_FRAME"))
```

You can take the reference from this link code also for searching elements:
"https://github.com/PrajinkyaPimpalghare/TimeSheet-Automation/blob/master/time_sheet_automation.py" Refer from line 94 to 108 for accessing elements in different way and also in different frame.